# Java: How to input time as string and calculate difference

Tags: java, time

I want to make a java program where the user enters a start time and an end time. from there I want the program to calculate the difference between the times? 
This should be the output

```
Enter first time: 12:56 pm
Enter second time: 1:03 pm
time difference is 7 minutes
```

All i just know is the formula to how to calculate and find the minutes.

Comment: Do a search through the Java 8 Time API or JodaTime (hint LocalTime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sorry I'm not quite clear with what you need. If you want to convert the time entered by the user to a time stamp and then calculate the difference, this would help:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Time {
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Enter first time (hh:mm aa): ");
 String time = input.nextLine();
 System.out.println();
 System.out.print("Enter second time (hh:mm aa): ");
 String time2 = input.nextLine();
 System.out.println();
 DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
 Date d1 = sdf.parse(time);
 Date d2 = sdf.parse(time2);

 System.out.println("Time: " + sdf.format(d1));
 System.out.println("Time: " + sdf.format(d2));
    if(d1.after(d2)){
     long diffMs = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
     long diffSec = diffMs / 1000;
     long min = diffSec / 60;
     long sec = diffSec % 60;
     System.out.println("The difference is "+min+" minutes and "+sec+" seconds.");
    }

    if(d1.before(d2)){
     long diffMs = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
     long diffSec = diffMs / 1000;
     long min = diffSec / 60;
     long sec = diffSec % 60;
     System.out.println("The difference is "+min+" minutes and "+sec+" seconds.");
    }

    if(d1.equals(d2)){
     System.out.println("The difference is 0 minutes and 0 seconds.");
    }

 }
}
```

The only limitation is that you have to limit your user to enter the time in the given format, allowing user to enter time in any format will make things bad for you to handle.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: i try to run your given program. but there is a problem. here is the error 
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12:00 "
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)

Comment: Yes that is what I said... User has to enter the date in a format that we are requesting him to.. Currently the format is HH:mm:ss... If you want user to enter in HH:mm... go ahead and change this in the code `DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");` to this `DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");`

Comment: yup, sorry my wrong. but the calculation i think is wrong? i entered 12:56 and second time is  1:03 
the answer should be 7 minutes right? but the output gave me 713 minutes and 0 seconds.

Comment: So... I'm using.. HH:mm... in the format... that makes it 24 hours format... use `DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");` and the user input will be like this : `12:56 pm` and `1:06 pm`.. to elaborate `HH` is used for 24 hours format whereas `hh` fo 12 hours.. Will work for sure!... I have also made the changes to the code I have provided.. you can just copy and run it directly..

Comment: thank you @Prateek :) you have such a beautiful soul

Answer (score 0):

```
String startTime = "08/16/2011 12:56:00";
String endTime = "08/16/2011 13:56:00";

// Customize your own date format
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.setTime(format.parse(startTime));
long startMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();

c.setTime(format.parse(endTime));
long endMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();

System.out.println("time difference is " + ((endMillis - startMillis)/1000) + " seconds");
```

Answer (score 0):

To accept time from user in HH:MM:SS format using regular expression

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class GetTime {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String ip="";
    String pattern="^([01]?\\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\\d):([0-5]?\\d)$";

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the time");
    ip=sc.nextLine();
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
     Matcher m = r.matcher(ip);
     if(m.find())
     {
         System.out.println("Time"+m.group(0));
         System.out.println("hh "+m.group(1));
         System.out.println("mm "+m.group(2));
         System.out.println("ss "+m.group(3));
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH! format mismatch");
     }
 }
}
```